# Raise an error based on results of other task

Tags: ansible

I am using the **postgresql_db** module that is part of Ansible. For example with something like

```
- name: Database
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ vars[item + '_database_name_version']  }}"
    login_host: "{{ vars[item + '_database_host'] }}"
    login_password: "{{ vars[item + '_database_admin_password'] }}"
    login_user: "{{ vars[item + '_database_admin_username'] }}"
    port: "{{ vars[item + '_database_port'] }}"
    state: restore
    target: "{{ backup_restore[item]['db_tar'] }}"
  when: backup_restore[item]['db_tar'] is defined
  with_items: '{{ backup_restore }}'
  register: db_restore
```

When I debug output *db_restore* I see

```
TASK [backup : db_restore] *****************************************************
ok: [myapp] => {
    "db_restore": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "cmd: ****",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "ca_cert": null,
                        "conn_limit": "",
                        "db": "myapp_0_1_0",
                        "encoding": "",
                        "lc_collate": "",
                        "lc_ctype": "",
                        "login_host": "1.1.1.2",
                        "login_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
                        "login_unix_socket": "",
                        "login_user": "ansible",
                        "maintenance_db": "postgres",
                        "name": "myapp_0_1_0",
                        "owner": "",
                        "port": 5432,
                        "session_role": null,
                        "ssl_mode": "prefer",
                        "state": "restore",
                        "target": "/backup/tmp/myapp-myapp/myapp_daily/databases/PostgreSQL.sql.gz",
                        "target_opts": "",
                        "template": ""
                    }
                },
                "item": "myapp",
                "msg": "",
                "rc": 0,
                "stderr": "ERROR:  relation \"myapp_table\" already exists\n",
                "stderr_lines": [
                    "ERROR:  relation \"myapp_table\" already exists"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Although there is an error during execution of this module as visible in **stderr**, the Ansible **postgresql_db** module also returns **"failed": false**. So it looks like it is ignoring any errors that might occur while running commands to restore the database.

Now I want to add a task to check *db_restore* for *stderr* attribute and if present, raise an error so that the user is made aware of the problems.

How can I raise an error? Is there an error module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a module to raise errors which is called fail (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html)

```
# Example playbook using fail and when together
- fail:
    msg: The system may not be provisioned according to the CMDB status.
  when: cmdb_status != "to-be-staged"
```

Another possible way is to use failed_when.

```
- name: Fail task when the command error output prints FAILED
  command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in command_result.stderr"
```

I would recommend you to read the ansible page on error handling (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

Comment: strongly agree with your answer. But maybe a `any_errors_fatal` on play level would suffice too.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with @Stefan Wegener's answer, but want to add another possibility.
I'm curious if your problem only occurs because of the loop you wrapped around your task.

Another *possible* solution would be to add the `any_errors_fatal: true` clause on play level like described in the Ansible documentation:

```
- hosts: somehosts
  any_errors_fatal: true
  roles:
    - myrole
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#aborting-the-play
for reference.

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it didn't help.